# scikit learn train_test_split with 2 features

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have a scikit-learn script to classify some ads and predict the CTR (click-through rate). It works well with 1 feature (the text). Unfortunately some other things matter. For example: the position (this would be stored in `order.position`).

I searched a lot on Google, but I can not figure out how to:

1. add this 2nd feature
2. add this to the line

   ```
   text=["Order now - click here"]
   ```

so that I can test, for instance: What would be the CTR if `text="asdf"` and `position = 3`.

This is the working code for text only, no position:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

X = orders.Text
y = orders.CTR

from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=1)

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
vect = CountVectorizer(analyzer='word')
vect.fit(X_train)
X_train_dtm = vect.transform(X_train)
X_test_dtm = vect.transform(X_test)

from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
clf = MultinomialNB()
clf.fit(X_train_dtm, y_train)

text=["Order now - click here"]
v_text = vect.transform(text).toarray()

erg=clf.predict(v_text)
print(erg)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way for split is to make all of your dataset into one dataframe first. For example, if you have following data

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

text = ['first row', 'second row', 'third row', 'fourth row'] # orders.text
position = [1, 2, 3, 4] # orders.Postion
y = [1, 0, 0 ,1]

df = pd.DataFrame(np.vstack([text, position]).T, columns=['text', 'position'])
```

You can use the same `train_test_split` to split dataframe and then you can select each column of the dataframe and process later on

```
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
df = pd.DataFrame(np.vstack([text, position]).T, columns=['text', 'position'])
df_train, df_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df, y)
```

Then you can create document-term matrix using `CountVectorizer`

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
vect = CountVectorizer()
vect.fit(df_train.text)
X_text_train = vect.transform(df_train.text) # documents-terms matrix of training set
X_text_test = vect.transform(df_test.text) # documents-terms matrix of testing set
```

**Adding position features**

If you want to add another column of position feature to documents-terms matrix, you can use `scipy.sparse` with method `hstack` to add additional column of feature e.g.

```
import scipy.sparse as sp
X_position_train = np.atleast_2d(df_train.position.astype(int)).T
X_train = sp.hstack((X_text_train, X_position_train))

X_position_test = np.atleast_2d(df_test.position.astype(int)).T
X_test = sp.hstack((X_text_test, X_position_test))
```

Then train your model on `X_train` and test it on `X_test`.

Comment: Sorry, its not working. It gives me NameError: name 'text_train' is not defined

Comment: Ah, nice catch. I just fixed the typos

Comment: I did fix it again, can you check?

Comment: Ok, thanks again. now it runs without error. but how can i now predict something, like

text=["Order now - click here"]
Position=1
#return the expected ctr.

Comment: Yes. You can transform your input to vector e.g. `X_pred = sp.hstact((vect.tranform(text), Position))` then put it in your trained classifier.